# How to translate tags (taxonomies) in Hugo?

Tags: internationalization, taxonomy, hugo

I am trying to translate tags in Hugo.

My tags are only declared in the metadata of my posts:

```
---
author: arthur.sw
date: 2007-01-01T00:00:35Z
tags:
  - experiment
  - reflection
---

... post content ...
```

I translated them in my language files:

`/i18n/en.toml`:

```
[Experiment]
one = "Experiment"
other = "Experiments"

[Reflection]
one = "Reflection"
other = "Reflections"
```

`/i18n/fr.toml`:

```
[Experiment]
one = "Expérience"
other = "Expériences"

[Reflection]
one = "Réflexion"
other = "Réflexions"
```

But it never translates the tags, no matter if I use capital letters or not.

I also tried to modify my `layouts/_default/list.html`:

```
[...]

        <h1 class='title'>
          {{- if eq .Kind "taxonomy" -}}
          <span class='taxonomy-type'>
            {{- ( ( i18n .Data.Singular 1 ) | default .Data.Singular ) | title -}}
            {{- print ": " -}}
          </span>
          {{- end -}}

          {{- i18n .Title -}}

        </h1>

[...]
```

(I added `i18n` before `.Title` to translate the taxonomy name) But this does not work either.

How can I translate tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every tag is part of the taxonomy. Categories are another example - both types are pre-defined in Hugo already.

The way multi-language pages in Hugo work is that you would have two separate files to fill with the different content. What you need to know here is that taxonomy is also something that you would directly translate in the respective content file, nowhere else.

In your particular case, if you put the tags as translated tags into your post files, they will show up in each of the translated pages.

This really seems obvious but what you also recognize quite soon is that if you go to the taxonomy list page (for example `<URL>/tags/`), then you would see all tags for the default language. If you switch tho another language, let's say French, it will likely go to another URI like `<URL>/fr/tags/` and show all tags for that particular language.
Next, what you would expect here is that you can click on any of the tags and see what pages are related to it. Yes you can - but switching the language on that particular overview page will show you that there is no such tag for the other language (unless they are named exactly the same, which sometimes might happen).

This is where it becomes a little inconvenient for Hugo to make the connection between the two tags, you will want to create additional template files under `/taxonomy/tag/<mytagname>.fr.md` with a `translationKey` attribute in the front matter that will contain the english name in lower case.

This is what is called "bypass default linking" and you may read more about it from the respective [Hugo documentation page](https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#bypassing-default-linking).